# How to call doInBackground on application load

Tags: android

Can we call the **`doInBackground()`** process without using any button `onClick()`?Can i call it on the loading of the application in android in `onCreate()` method?

Comment: Yes of-course. The onCreate method is the starting point of your activity. Its similar to the main method of Java

Comment: ok..so it can be done by calling execute method on the object of the class that extends Asynch Task?Thanks

Comment: If you wonder why you get down votes, the reason is your cryptic writing. You never mentioned an AsyncTask but the method doInBackground... you should consider a bit more explaining and more details.

Answer (score 2):

You are free to do that. You can't call `doInBackground()` directly but you can invoke `execute()` without problems.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        new MyAsyncTask().execute();
    }
}
```